# Tailwind CSS make div height full height background image

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am writing something where the user will input an image and then add a heading which will be overlayed. I do not know the height of the image but I want the image to stretch to full width and the height of the image itself.

I have tried bg-cover but the size of the div is based on its content and not the image.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add some code of what you have tried?

Comment: <div class="w-full bg-[url('{{$img}}')] ">
    some text
</div>

Answer (score 0):

To make the div occuy the entire screen (viewport) you could simply use the class `min-h-screen` on the div. It is the tailwind class for: `min-height: 100vh`:

```css
div { 
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Tailwind -->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="min-h-screen bg-cover">Small Content</div>
```

Comment: I do not necessarily want the div with the image background to be full screen, just the div to be the height of the image.

Comment: that does not work with background-images. background-images are no content and as such occupy no space. you need an image then and size the div based on the image while you move the text out of flow with `position: absolute`